# Ruby on Rails: Validating the Month and Year of a card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, haml

I am using card details in my application and I want to validate those, so that whenever a user adds his/her card details it will show an error message for the past month and year.

This is the code that I am using -

```
.task-name-container.required
        %label Expiration Date
        = f.input :month, collection: %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12), label: false, required: true, input_html: { class: "task-select #{'error' unless f.object.errors[:expiration_date].empty?}" }
        = f.input :year, collection: (Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)), label: false, required: true, input_html: { class: "task-select year #{'error' unless f.object.errors[:expiration_date].empty?}" }
```

Currently this code is allowing the user to add the past month.

Is anyone having any idea how to add that error message based on condition in haml file?

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What is a "card"? What are you trying to validate? Please clarify what you have tried, what your intended behavior is, etc.

Comment: @engineersmnky Here card means 'Credit/Debit Card' and I am trying to put validation on month and year fields so that a user cannot add the past date for card.

Comment: I would add that information to the question. Additionally I would highly recommend you not do this yourself due to innumerable compliance concerns and other nuances of credit card processing. Most credit card processing gateways and clearing houses will validate this information "for you" though an API or other method of communication.

Comment: reference: https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to add validation to class (assume it is Card):

```
class Card
  validate :is_past?

  private

  def is_past?
    submitted_date = Date.new(year, month).end_of_month
    today = Date.current

    errors.add :expiration_date, "Your card is expired" if today > submitted_date
  end
end
```

Comment: Credit cards expire at the end of the month of expiration `Date.new` with just month and year will return the beginning of the month. e.g. if my card expires "06/2021" your validation as of today will say my card is expired however it is not as of yet.

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky.  Additionally, year and month presence check.

Comment: you should check time instead of date: [reference](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb#L399)